# Are there any git commands that will explicitly destroy a commit?

Tags: git, git-reset

Does Git ever truly destroy commits or just orphan them? I am aware that the git garbage collector will remove orphaned commits when run with `git gc` on whatever interval is set in git config. Are there any other cases that will delete a commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git may truly destroy some object, including an unreferenced commit, eventually; but it may not.  Read through to the end for why this is so.

The most direct control is available through [`git prune`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-prune.html), [`git repack`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-repack.html), and [`git prune-packed`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-prune-packed.html).  Running [`git gc`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) runs all of these, and more.  The main problem with assuming that `git prune`, or even `git gc --prune=now`, will do the trick is that objects that are now unreachable may have been *packed*.

In general, you should expire reflogs first, since removing expired reflog entries may cause objects to become unreachable.  Using `git gc` gets all of this done in the right order, in a relatively safe manner: expire reflogs first, then prune (carefully), then repack, then prune-packed.  The `prune` step tosses *loose* objects that are unreferenced *and themselves expired*.<sup>1</sup>  After that, the other steps repack older objects that are in use, and delete objects that have just become packed.

This sequence of events is why we need `git repack -d`, or even `-ad`, followed by `git prune-packed`.  However, if some packs are marked with a `.keep` file, those packs will remain, and if they contain otherwise-unreferenced objects, those objects will remain as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since multiple Git commands may be run in parallel, it's wise to provide a grace period during which unreferenced objects live on, in case they are about to become referenced.  Note that it is `git gc` that inserts the default 14 day grace period; `git prune` defaults to `--expire=now` rather than `--expire=2.weeks.ago`.  This gives Git commands 336 hours to get their work done and cement references: e.g., `git commit` runs `git write-tree` followed by `git commit-tree`, and this tree and commit are unreferenced until `git commit` also updates the current branch name.  Normally, this whole process takes just a few milliseconds, so 336 hours should be plenty of time.

Answer (score 1):

[`git-prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune) has the explicit mission statement of deleting orphaned objects.